# When is this Laurent series convergent?

Tags: matrix-equations, laurent-series

$S=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} A^iz^{-i-1}$, where $A$ is a matrix, I need to know when this is convergent in bit detail. Thanks for helping

Comment: This is nonsensical. You have to specify what $A$ and $z$ are. This multiplication isn't always possible.

Comment: $A$ is $n\times n$ real matrix and $z$ is a complex variable

Comment: Is $Az = f(z)$, where $f$ is the corresponding linear map? Or is $z\in\mathbb C$?

Comment: $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Okay, this is a functional series, then. What are some obvious cases when the series diverges?

Comment: The answer is given that this is convergent when $|z|>\rho(A)$ where $\rho(A)$ is a spectral radius of $A$, but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63201/discussion-between-miosaki-and-alvin-lepik).